# How to translate a scientific term to Vietnamese?

Tags: english, translation, vietnamese

What is the guide, in general, for translating scientific terms from English to other language? I know, of course, that we need a person who have good competence on the field containing that word. Nevertheless, that person mostly don't have good competence on linguistics. So, what is the guide for this situation? Please explain in detail. Thank you.

Comment: Is the term native English or borrowed from Latin or Greek? Also, to what language do u want to translate?

Comment: It's *[Chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality)*. It borrowed from Greek. I want to translate it to Vietnamese. But I want to ask in general.

Comment: In Russian it's хиральность, similar to English.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Russian.

Comment: That's why I put the Russian word here so u to see it. U should check how Greek words usually rendered in Vietnamese.

Comment: Do you mean by looking for the meaning of the root in Greek and try translating it to Vietnamese. I have already tried this way. However me and my friend don't consensus on the translation. I know that the translation is vary from person, but I want to know if there is another way to identify which is better.

Comment: Note also that the suffix -al- is of Latin origin, so the wordform possibly should follow the Latin rules. Both English and Russian has borrowed the suffix from Latin language (I do not know for Vietnamese, whether they have the same suffix)

Comment: Thanslating meaning? Definitely not for Russian, but I do not know what do u do in Vietnam.

Comment: So, transliterate the "chiral" from Latin language (not the English pronounciation), then add a suffix meaning it is an abstract noun.

Comment: can you please explain for me a little bit about translating from English to Russian? I have tried googling a bit but find no clue.

Comment: This word has a root of Greek origin (χειρ) and Latin form (chiralis). So, remove the ending to get "chiral", transliterate to "хираль", add abstract noun suffix "ность" -> "хиральность". The same is in English. Skip transliteration, because English usually borrows Latin forms as is, add abstract noun suffix "-ity", get "chirality". The same is in French: "chiralite". The same is in German: "Chiralität"

Comment: Well, English to Vietnamese translate.google.com [has](https://translate.google.com/#en/vi/Chirality) the word 'chirality', there are several synonyms, so you only need a consultation from a Vietnamese specialist in the field the term is going to be used.

Comment: @Anixx: so with your recipe, "chiral" is "thủ" and the suffix which forming nouns denoting quality or condition is "tính". So it will be "thủ tính"? Note that Vietnamese is a [Austroasiatic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austroasiatic_languages), which is far different from Western languages (I don't know much about linguistics, although I do have read some not-basic-not-advance books about it).

Comment: @YellowSky: not so much Vietnamese books are datafication, so Google Translate is not good. And indeed, the translation of "chirality" is exactly the same with "symmetry", while the concept of these two words are not.

Comment: I think your question should be named not "from English" but "to Vietnamese". Because it does not depend on English properties(and the word itself is not of English origin) but heavily depends on Vietnamese properties. As you can see, the practice in Vietnamese is sufficiently different from English, Russian, German, French, Estonian and other European languages. Answers concerning these languages will not help you with Vietnamese case.

Comment: @Anixx: I see, thank you so much for your help

Comment: There is no magic formula for translating from one language to another. You need to find a Vietnamese monolingual or bilingual technical dictionary.

Comment: I've never seen this term, but in mathematics I only see "đối xứng trục" or "đối xứng gương" that may be closest in meaning

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: No. They are not. Chiral symmetry and especially chirality are popular terms in science.

Comment: but the hands are also just reflections through a mirror/plane, so what's different between chirality and reflection?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: See this Ed-TED clip: [What is chirality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d6HV7Mjy5w) (Vietnamese subbed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the translation of scientific terms is one of the greatest areas where a "normative procedure" is in place (some could argue it is a form of [linguistic prescription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription)). In the case of Vietnamese though, there is no central body for linguistic regulation similar to the *[Académie Française](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_Fran%C3%A7aise)* in the case of the French language. I believe that there is no official regulator in the case of the Vietnamese language at present.

However, when users of a language seek a source for language regulation, they may turn to a variety of sources. Monolingual dictionaries have always been the bastion of linguistic self-regulation in modern literate societies. With the rise of the Internet, certain websites have become major sources of such information.

Trust in a source's accuracy is a major factor for such sources, especially so in the scientific community. In modern science, with its emphasis on traceability, it is entirely possible for a translated paper to be the reference for a new scientific concept or finding in any language. However, a simple concept like chirality will be likely be part of more fundamental educational training, and perhaps its entry into the language might have pre-dated the first scientific papers in the language.

---

For such a case then, the new word has come into the language like any other new word in the language: as a [loanword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword), or possibly a calque. A dictionary for the translator that specialises in a particular field may be a possibility. In Vietnamese, there is [one such English-Vietnamese medical dictionary](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Pj6yBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT481), which does employ the word "chiral" in Vietnamese:

- trung tâm *chiral*: trung tâm của dyssymmetry trong một phân từ

For actual usage one can consult the wider Internet. [There is a forum post dating from 2007](http://z3.invisionfree.com/superstudents_10a/index.php?showtopic=68) in Vietnamese, where "chiral" is used by default, but a gloss is given too.

- Hai bàn tay của chúng ta có tính chiral (*đối xứng bàn tay*)

This looks like a calque: the components are the Sino-Vietnamese phrase "đối xứng" [對稱] meaning "symmetry", and the phrase "bàn tay" for "hand". This has also been used in Vietnamese Wikipedia:

- Monosaccarit có bốn nguyên tử cacbon trở lên có thể chứa nhiều nguyên tử cacbon *đối xứng bàn tay*

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I really appreciate it. Sorry for the late respond. Actually, there is a *[different](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990192/what-is-the-different-between-chirality-and-chiral-symmetry)* between "chiral" and "chirality" in mathematics. The "chiral symmetry" is *đối xứng bàn tay* but the "chirality" is not.